# MySQL Database Structure for Followers

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to implement a follow/favorite system. I can think of 2 ways of implementing a database/table structure but am unsure of which one to implement. Which one of these would be considered best practices and most importantly why?

I put all of my followers in a single string. By putting all followers in a single string it reduces the amount of redundant rows.

Ex.

id (1) || user_id (1) || follower_ids (2, 3, 45)

```
'CREATE TABLE `users` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';

'CREATE TABLE `follow` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `follower_ids` text NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';
```

OR

I put each follow_id individually but adds redundancy by having 3 rows for the same user_id.

Ex.

id (1) || user_id (1) || follower_id (2)

id (2) || user_id (1) || follower_id (3)

id (3) || user_id (1) || follower_id (45)

```
'CREATE TABLE `users` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';

'CREATE TABLE `follow` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `follower_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';
```

Comment: non of them. They both miss indexes, probably the most important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second option with a slight modification on the field names, as both the follower and the followed are BOTH user_id's. As mentioned by John, add foreign keys to both of the *_user_id fields in the follow table.

Additionally, never have plural table names. 'user' and 'follow' are sufficient. I personally prefer tables like 'follow' to have a prefix like 'xref_' so that i know it's simply a cross reference table allowing a many-to-many relationship (A user can follow many users, and a user may have many following users).

```
'CREATE TABLE `user` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';

'CREATE TABLE `follow` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `followed_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `follower_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';
```

Comment: Why are you refraining from using plural names? Can you please explain what's bad in it?

Comment: @IstiyakTailor industry standard for Relational database table names is singular.

Comment: source please. As far as I know most of the guide recommends following either of the approach. Either go all singular or plural. The point is being consistency.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is neither. You should have a middle table between follow table and followers table. The middle table have only two columns. follow_id and followers_id. 
With this kind of approach you omit the disadvantages of two solutions you have mentioned. You do not have to proccess a string and you have not duplicate entries and the performances with only indexes included are pretty fast.

```
'CREATE TABLE `follow` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';

'CREATE TABLE `user` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` varchar(255) unsigned NOT NULL,
        ....
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1';
'CREATE TABLE `follow_user` (
        `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `follower_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
)
```

Cause you change your post a lot, i think that your second approach is better if followers are the same as users. Because you only store the indexex of follow and users and a good select query to see what a single user follows something is way more better than parsing and searching a string The duplicate entries are no problem cause they are only indexes and there's no problem to that.

Comment: Can you give me a table structure example so I can get a better grasp?

Comment: So how would you go about querying this information? Like for instance adding a follower?

I'm not exactly sure why you would need a followers table when you already have a users table with all the users (you named your user table follow)?

Comment: Followers are users? if so let me change the code. You need a middle table between users and follow

Comment: Your second approach is much better. I edited my post. See below the code to know why